# Android Studio Error Emulator OpengIES

Tags: android-emulator

When I created my first Android Project and run it the following error is show:

could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

and I try to solve this problem using the following steps but not solve:
-Disable OpenGLES emulation support by renaming \tools\lib\libOpenglRender.dll to libOpenglRender.dll.disabled.

-Reduce the amount of memory used by the emulator. Try 900MB, if that doesn't work, try 800MB, if that doesn't work, try 700MB, you get the idea. (I suggest start with a rather low value of 512 MB)

-Typing in the resolution manually rather than picking WXVGA720 or 800

please help me